# Failed to deserialize json object to map

Tags: java, json

I know there are similar posts about this issue but please read carefully before marking as duplicate.

I have a text string that I want to convert to a JSON line/instance and then to a Java map variable, so I can access each attribute individualy.
This is my string:

```
{"S3_r5_Ahf": "0.00025", "S15_r6_Alf": "-0.00514", "S6_r4_Alf": "-0.00126", "S12_r9_Alf": "-0.00595", "S13_r8_Ahf": "0.00018", "S1_r9_Alf": "-0.00385", "S8_r10_Alf": "-0.00849" }
```

Using the GSON library I converted the string to a json object using:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(s);
```

And this works great, the output being:

```
"{\"S3_r5_Ahf\": \"0.00025\", \"S15_r6_Alf\": \"-0.00514\", \"S6_r4_Alf\": \"-0.00126\", \"S12_r9_Alf\": \"-0.00595\", \"S13_r8_Ahf\": \"0.00018\", \"S1_r9_Alf\": \"-0.00385\", \"S8_r10_Alf\": \"-0.00849\"
```

The problem is when I try to convert it to a map by using:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> retMap = gson.fromJson(json,type);
```

When I try to print retMap I get the error: The JsonDeserializer MapTypeAdapter failed to deserialize json object to map.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: The string you used first is already JSON, the second one is a JSON escaped so it fail to be deserialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Java string `s` is already in JSON format (i.e., a "JSON line/instance"), so you don't need to call `gson.toJson()` on it (this turns it into a JSON string, which is not a JSON map, and thus can't be parsed as one).

Just try:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> retMap = gson.fromJson(s,type);
```